# Underscores in class names

Tags: php, class, symfony, namespaces

In my Symfony2 application I sometimes have to use some external APIs, classes, etc. which do not follow the PSR-0 standard.

When I try to use them with the "use" and "new" statements, I get an error that the class was not found. How can I make Symfony load classes which include underscores, for example Some_Class ?

Comment: PSR-0 allows people to use underscores...

Comment: I've made a simple A_B class in A_B.php file and the script says that it has not been found. But when I rename it to AB and change the file's name to AB.php, it works fine.

Comment: the class `A_B` should live in `src/A/B.php` (or any other autoloaded directory)

Comment: class A_B inside A/B.php throws this exception ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "A_B". The "use" statement: use Acme\CoreBundle\Test\A_B;

Comment: the A/B is inside Acme/CoreBundle/Test of course

Answer (score 1):

Is class A_B making use of the namespace? If so then you should be able to call it with is FQN EX:

```
use Acme\CoreBundle\Test\A_B;
```

Otherwise you need to use a require statement to load the file and that will load the class to the global namespace.

```
require_once 'Acme/CoreBundle/Test/A_B.php';
```

Im pretty sure thats how it works. Dont shoot me if im wrong.